# Set background image to CollapsingToolbarLayout in android 6

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

When I use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in android version 5 or less it works perfectly fine but in android version 6 it doesn't show the image.
as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#FFFF"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/card_view"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

in android 5 or less
[image]

in android 6
[image]

Comment: tried adding android:adjustviewbouds? to imageview

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work in this case.

Comment: @Mahsa tried to adding `src` to `background` and height `wrap_content` to `match_parent`.

Comment: remove  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from your collapsing toolbar layout

Comment: @Ironman Thanks for your help, I did what you told earlier, but it didn't work. I would be grateful if you give me another solution.

Comment: @Mahsa then what is problem occure.

Comment: @HourGlass Many thanks for your helps, I tested it, but still doesn't show the image.

Comment: @HourGlass I set background instead of src in ImageView  and set android:layout_height="match_parent" in AppBarLayout tag, as you said. I also set background to the same image in CollapsingToolbarLayout. I expected to see the image but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Include your `card_view` after `AppBarLayout` and set`height` for `AppBarLayout` instead `ImageView` and make `ImageView` `height` `match_parent`